# jScrollPane resizing for VISIBLE content

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I'm using jScrollPane to create scrollbars for my website and I have an unordered list that loads a variable amount of list items.  On the page load, the scrollbar's size fits properly to the FULL list.  However, using jQuery I have classes on the list items to show and hide certain list items with certain classes depending on button presses.  How do I force the jScrollPane to reevaluate the size of the visible information so as to accomodate size changes of the visible list items.

Here is the code that I used in my java file, but clearly it's wrong because it doesn't resize properly, presumably because there are still the list items in unordered list, it's simply the case that their display status is set to 'none'.

```
scrollbarSizeChange = function() {
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: false});
$('.scroll-pane').data('jsp').reinitialise();
}
```

I suppose more succinctly put: How do I reset the jScrollPane scrollbar size to accomodate list items with the 'display: inline-block' property and exclude list items with the 'display: none' property?

Comment: And how exactly are you calling scrollbarSizeChange?

Comment: I have .click() pieces set up that, among other things, calls that function.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it needed to call the `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: false});` line on every call? Isn't that a constructor?